# Magento 2.3 Prices Dissapearing

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, price

I am currently seeing an intermitent issue on our Magento 2.3 store with prices dissapearing.

We have simple products but with MageWorx Advances Product Options to create dependable product options.

Every once in a while a product price will just dissapear and be completely blank, this is completely baffeling me, does anyone have any suggetions or experienced this before?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, so if anyone is experiencing the same issue it could be due to the following:

Check price scope, our price scope was changed to website

Once we changed price scope back to global the issues went away.

I don't have anything more informative as to why this occured, but at least we found the issue and resolved it.